# `URLByAppendingPathComponent` not accepting argument

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following in my program:

```
return [directory URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

checking with a debugger, `fileName` is `__NSCFString * @"OA1aK7ikkYq5cK5"` (so it contains `@"OA1aK7ikkYq5cK5"`)

`directory` is a URL retrieved with:

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Why does this throw this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10fa01de0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns an array of strings, not URLs. You should be calling

```
NSURL *directory = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
```

**EDIT**

Just wanted to clarify that it's an array of `NSPathStore2` objects, which is a subclass of `NSString`.